# zip and formset together in django template

Tags: django, django-forms

im trying to use formset_factory and something from my db in zip and use it in to template 
here is my form:

```
class class_attandance_form(forms.ModelForm):
    choise1 = [(True, 'ح'),
               (False, 'غ')]
    choise2 = [('مثبت', 'مثبت'),
               ('منفی', 'منفی')]
    attendance = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=choise1)
    activity = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=choise2)
    score = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=3)
    user = forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        model = Class_Book
        fields = ('activity','attendance','score','user')
```

and here is my view:

```
def class_attendance(request):
    term = Term.objects.filter(lesson__in=[1,])
    form1 = formset_factory(class_attandance_form,max_num=len(term),extra=len(term))
    form = form1()
    term_form = zip(list(term), list(form))
    if request.method == 'POST':
       query = form1(request.POST or None)
       if query.is_valid():
           q = query.cleaned_data
           print(q)

return render(request,'teacher/class_attendance.html',{'term_form':term_form})
```

and my temp is :

```
<form role="form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table cellspacing="0" class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ردیف</th>
            <th>نام و نام خانوادگی</th>
            <th>حضور و غیاب</th>
            <th colspan="2">نمره</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        {% for term, form in term_form %}
            <tr class="class_book" id="{{ term.id }}">
                <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                <td>{{ term.student.first_name }} {{ term.student.last_name }}</td>
                <td>
                    {{ form.attendance }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ form.activity }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ form.score }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{ form.user }}
            <script>
            $('#id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-user').val({{ term.id }})
            </script>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button id="submit" class="button" type="submit">ثبت</button>

</form>
```

why when i use `query = form1(request.POST or None)` i got this error
"ManagementForm Data is Missing When Using Formset Prefix"
and can you tell me what `{{formset.managment_form}}` work for

Comment: It is for solving that problem. Why don't you use it?

Comment: how can i use that??

Comment: ... put it in the template?

Comment: dud iknow where i must put that, but i dont have a formset in my template i have zip and how can i use formset.management_form in this specific code

Comment: Well why don't you just pass the formset?

Comment: i need that queryset too , dont worry i done it by my self; trial and error do his job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try a lot and i find how can i do this you must send your `formset` and your `queryset` in zip and send your `formset` again for do `{{formset.managment_form}}` in your template form the view cod is:

```
def class_attendance(request):
    term = Term.objects.filter(lesson__in=[1,])
    form1 = formset_factory(class_attandance_form,max_num=len(term),extra=len(term))
    form = form1()
    term_form = zip(list(term), list(form))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = form1(request.POST or None)
        print(query.errors)
        if query.is_valid():
            q = query.cleaned_data
            print('sss',q)

    return render(request,'teacher/class_attendance.html',{'term_form':term_form,'form':form})
```

and form is:

```
class class_attandance_form(forms.ModelForm):
    choise1 = [(True, 'ح'),
               (False, 'غ')]
    choise2 = [(True, 'مثبت'),
               (False, 'منفی')]
    attendance = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=choise1,
                                   widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'btn_attendance'}))
    activity = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=choise2,
                                 widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'btn_attendance'}))
    score = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=3,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'text-field blue-field', 'placeholder': 'نمره'}))
    user = forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=20,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'student'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Class_Book
        fields = ('activity','attendance','score')
```

and my template is:

```
<form role="form" dir="rtl" id="frm" autocomplete="off" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.management_form }}
    <table cellspacing="0" class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ردیف</th>
            <th>نام و نام خانوادگی</th>
            <th>حضور و غیاب</th>
            <th colspan="2">نمره</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        {% for term, form in term_form %}
            <tr class="class_book" id="">
                <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                <td>{{ term.student }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0">
                        {{ form.attendance }}
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0">
                        {{ form.activity }}
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.score }}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{ form.user }}
            <script>
            $('#id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-user').val({{ term.student.id }})
            </script>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button id="submit" class="button" type="submit">ثبت</button>

</form>
```

i hope its work for you guys